# Macro to populate data fields from Workbook1 into Workbook 2

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping someone could help me with some code I've been working on.

Basically what I am trying to do is copy certain pieces of data from Workbook 1 and copy them into Workbook 2.

The data that I am copying starts in Workbook 1 at Cell A9 and the range is dynamic. So for example it might start at A9 and have 10 values ranging down to A18, but this changes all the time so I need to make sure the loop stops when it reaches the last value of Column A.

I've tested the below code, and it's successfully copying A9 over to A2.  Now I'm trying to work out how to modify the code so it copies all the dynamic values from A9 - A-n with a loop.

```
TWBWS.Range("A2").Value = OWBWS.Range("A9").Value
```

Below is what I've tried so far.

```
Sub PopulateFields()

Workbooks("BUPA_LHC_Reconciliation_20171018204045.xlsx").Activate
Workbooks("BUPA_LHC_Reconciliation_20171018204045.xlsx").Worksheets("Unconfirmed").Activate

Dim twbrow_number As Integer
Dim owbrow_number As Integer
Dim OWBLastRow As Integer
Dim TWB As Workbook 'This workbook
Dim OWB As Workbook 'Other workbook
Dim TWBWS As Worksheet 'Data
Dim OWBWS As Worksheet 'Report worksheet, in OWB

owbrow_number = 8
twbrow_number = 1

Set TWB = Workbooks("LHC Report Email test v1.0.xlsm")
Set OWB = Workbooks("BUPA_LHC_Reconciliation_20171018204045.xlsx")
Set TWBWS = TWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set OWBWS = OWB.Worksheets("Unconfirmed")

OWBLastRow = OWBWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 2


Do
DoEvents

owbrow_number = owbrow_number + 1
twbrow_number = twbrownumber + 1

TWBWS.Range(Cells(twbrow_number, 1)).Value = OWBWS.Range(Cells(owbrow_number, 1)).Value

Loop Until owbrow_number = OWBLastRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last part of your code with:

```
    OWBLastRow = OWBWS.Cells(OWBWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 2

    TWBWS.Cells(2, "A").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value = OWBWS.Cells(9, "A").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value    

End Sub
```

That will copy the entire range in one go.

---

The statement copying the values could also be rewritten as

```
TWBWS.Range("A2:A" & OWBLastRow - 7).Value = OWBWS.Range("A9:A" & OWBLastRow).Value
```

---

Your loop approach would have worked if you had used:

```
TWBWS.Cells(twbrow_number, 1).Value = OWBWS.Cells(owbrow_number, 1).Value
```

Your problem was that you can't just pass a single cell reference as a parameter to a `Range`.  It either needs to be two cell references (defining top-left and bottom-right), or a string specifying an address, or a string specifying a range name.